# Why is (-1)^(2/3) equal to -1/2+(i sqrt(3))/2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can someone please explain to me how $(-1)^{\frac2 3}$ can be written as $\frac {-1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt3} 2$ ? Do you use the corrolation $(-1)^c = e^{(i c \pi)}$, where ${c}$ is a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
(-1)^{2/3} & = (e^{\pi i})^{2/3} \\
 & = e^{2/3\pi i} \\ 
 & = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right) \\
 & = -\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}
\end{align}

So yes, we did use $(-1)^c = e^{ic\pi}$, which uses the definition of the complex exponent $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ where the principal branch of the natural logarithm function is used.